# How to extract content between 2 curly braces using swift macos?

Tags: swift

i want to extract this content `any string content abcd@gmail.com any string content`

I tried many ways but it still doesn't work properly

Can you all help me extract that content?

```
let email = "abcd@gmail.com"
let content = "{any string content efgh@yahoo.com any string content} {any string content abcd@gmail.com any string content}{any string content klmn@yahoo.com any string content}"

let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\{(.*)"+email+"(.*)\\}")
let matches = regex.matches(in: content, range: NSRange(content.startIndex..., in: content))
                            for match in matches {
                                let swiftRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: content)!
                                print(content[swiftRange]) //any string content efgh@yahoo.com any string content} {any string content
}
```

Comment: What does "still doesn't work properly" mean?

Comment: Are you expecting to get an array of strings? It looks like your string has multiple entries in it.

Comment: The expression `.*` matches curly braces, so you are not confining your pattern to a single matching pair of curly braces.

Comment: This is Output: any string content efgh@yahoo.com any string content} {any string content

Comment: Yup, read my previous comment, I explained that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> i want to extract this content `any string content abcd@gmail.com any string content`

The trouble is that the expression `.*` matches curly braces, so you are not confining the search to a single matching pair of curly braces. Plus, it is greedy, whereas you want the *shortest* match so that you stop at the *first* matching right curly brace. What you want is something more like this:

```
let email = "abcd@gmail.com"
let content = "{any string content efgh@yahoo.com any string content} {any string content abcd@gmail.com any string content}{any string content klmn@yahoo.com any string content}"

let pattern = "\\{([^{}]*"+email+".*?)\\}"
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
if let result = regex.firstMatch(in: content, options: [], range: NSRange(content.startIndex..., in:content)) {
    let range = result.range(at: 1)
    if let srange = Range(range, in:content) {
        print(content[srange])
        // any string content abcd@gmail.com any string content
    }
}
```

As you can see, we got exactly the output you said you wanted. It is possible that what you said you wanted is not what you *really* wanted, but you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Would be prudent to escape the email if it's expected to be coming from somewhere else: `NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: email)`

Comment: @RobZombie a lot of things would be prudent, I'm just showing the OP the mistake that the question itself is about.

Comment: So is this a "typo" question, then? :)

Comment: @Cristik Arguably everything is a "typo"! :)))))

Answer (score 1):

you could just use this:

```
let arr = content.split(separator: "{").map{String($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).dropLast())}
if let result = arr.first(where: { $0.contains(email) }) {
    print("---> result: \(result)")
}
```